# Why 'more' does not work in help cmdlet of PowerShell here?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I want to see the help contents page by page in PS.

I try | more like:

help about_Debuggers|more

but still does not work and I get pages of info flowing at once.

Is there another way or what it shte correct way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm on windows 7 with powershell v3 and `more.com` command works as aspected. Check `gcm more` to see if there is some other more cmdlet called.

Answer (score 1):

'help' is a function that wraps a `Get-Help` call piped to the `more` utility. So by default you should get paged output.

When you execute your command you're actually sending output calling 'more' twice. 
That said, either way, it works for me. Testes on v3.  What do you get by just executing:

```
help about_Debuggers
```

Comment: No... It seems I have a special issue here. :)

Comment: @pencilcake what host are you using? The ISE won't page output.

Comment: I use ISE. And you are RIGHT! (But why it does not page out in ISE, this does not make sense at all! :( )

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use paging in ISE, ISE panes have scroll bars.

Comment: @pencilCake From [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/04/17/differences-between-the-ise-and-powershell-console.aspx): "The ISE has no pager." Explains a *lot* (I couldn't `more` a file I'd just made with `echo > out.txt` inside of PS ISE and it was driving me crazy -- turns out `more.com` expects a pager too) As that page suggests, try `gc function:more` to see what's up. `gc function:help` shows `help` also calls `more` -- `Get-Help @PSBoundParameters | more`

Comment: Very late reply, but i tend to use -showwindow from the script pane so: Get-help about_Debuggers -showwindow