# No PowerShell help in Docker using WindowServerCore

Tags: powershell, docker

I'm using Docker and WindowsServerCore base image to serve different PowerShell modules to some Ops. If I start the container and try to use the `Get-Help` cmdlet I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator> help *service*
more.com : The term 'more.com' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:9 char:19
+ } else { $input | more.com }
+                   ~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (more.com:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Any hints?

Thx

Comment: are you using the native containers in 2016 or Docker for Windows/Toolbox ?

Comment: I'm using Docker for Windows (OS = Win 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From these two questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44327514/powershell-helpfiles-not-displaying-correctly) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191548/why-more-does-not-work-in-help-cmdlet-of-powershell-here) state that `help` doesn't run as `Get-Help` as many commands do when run without `Get-` but is a function that pipes to `more.com`. Likely the executable `more.com` isn't included in the WindowsServerCore base image.

Comment: Thx, made my day!